# Get max datetime (db column) from a query subset using entity framework and linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have one SQL table from which I first need to select a subset of data (I guess?) and then get the record for which a datetime column contains the latest date and time.

The table is part of an entity framework data model and I need to use linq.

How do I get the latest record from that subset without selecting billions of records?

Is it possible to combine the .Max() statement with oter where clauses?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Of course, however I'm a newbie amd couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your query should look like this:

```
(from obj in ctx.Set 
    where condition
    orderby obj.Date descending
    select obj).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks, I'll try this.